# iOS: Where to learn UI/UX to give my apps "pop" and excitingness?

Tags: ios, user-interface, user-experience

Myself and other app developers I've spoken with have heard this before: "Your apps look too basic, too boring." I am wondering if there is an online course, or a blog or a book that I could refer to, to learn how to make my apps look and act wonderfully and give them excitingness. I am not a UI/UX person but I did take a Coursera UI design course, which confirmed what I already thought about UIs. Apparently there is more to learn... Like Socrates said, I know I don't know. As a solo app developer, I don't have a budget for a UI/UX person to help me, but I am willing to learn it myself.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [iOS Design Tools](http://ios.devtools.me), which has both plenty of technical and inspiration resources.

A personal favorite of mine (listed in there) is [pttrns](http://pttrns.com), which does an amazing job presenting some of the better designs in the App Store.